# trying to get time offset value in the code behind through a hidden field . but i get null string ("") instead of the offset

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

defined the function to get the time offset here.

```
`<script>
 function getTimeZone()
 {
 return new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
 }
 </script>`
```

Called that function here. And stored that value in a hidden field with id result.

```
`<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
$('#result').val(getTimeZone());
}
);
</script>`
```

But when i access the hidden field value , it returns : ""

```
  `int offset = Convert.ToInt16(result.Value);`
```

Can anyone help me understand why and give a solution for this problem.

Comment: It work perfect for me check https://jsfiddle.net/st7j78s2/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form like this:

```html
<form action='abc.html' method='post'>
    <input id='result' name='result'></input>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

And js:

```js
function getTimeZone() {
    return new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#result').val(getTimeZone());
});
```

The value will be in your form data, and you can refer to it in C# by it's name property from the request. So your value will be in:

```c#
Request.Form["result"]
```

JsFiddle for html and js: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/rtL7byeq/